# Why is relative positioning changing the order of my page?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a weird problem with my HTML and CSS code:

```
<header>
    <h1>title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <a href="">menu 1</a>
    <a href="">menu 1</a>
    <a href="">menu 1</a>
    <a href="">menu 1</a>
</nav>
```

```css
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
* {
    border: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Why does the `<nav>` appear above the `<header>` when they are both relatively positioned?

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aARyr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not, you just moved the header down below the nav. You specified a `top: 200px` to it, which moves it *down* 200px... Your nav appears in the place it *would have appeared* if that property wasn't there. It's moved down the height of the header from the top of the window. If you want to push the nav down too, you can add a `top: 200px` to it as well, but this just causes the problem of every other element needing to be relatively positioned 200px from the top of where it originally appears, which isn't very logical.

[image: Relative positioning]

What exactly are you trying to do? Did you mean to use `margin-top: 200px` instead, to move everything on the page down by 200px?

Answer (score 0):

```
position: relative; 
top: 200px;
```

This moves the header down 200px, putting it under the nav. It's only doing exactly what you told it to...

Answer (score 0):

The `<header>` has `top: 200px;` so it will be positioned 200 pixels from the top. The `<nav>` is not offset so appears as it should, at the top of the `<body>`.